# Segmentation fault of ImageMagick + Python ctypes

Tags: python, macos, imagemagick, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I am using ImageMagick library with Python `ctypes`. I wrote a following simple code, but it crashes with segmentation fault (`KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`) in Mac:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library

lib = CDLL(find_library('MagickWand'))
lib.MagickWandGenesis()
wand = lib.NewMagickWand()
lib.MagickReadImage(wand, 'mona-lisa.jpg')
lib.DestroyMagickWand(wand)
lib.MagickWandTerminus()
```

It works well in Linux and Windows both, but craches only in Mac OS X Lion. I built ImageMagick in various ways (official binary package, Homebrew, traditional `./configure && make`), but it crashed for every trial.

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00000000009a7638
0x000000010149a8d1 in MagickReadImage ()
```

Not only for `MagickReadImage()` function, `IsMagickWand()` function also crashes. I only guess `NewMagickWand()` returns a wrong pointer, or `ctypes` in Mac handles pointers incorrectly, but I’m not sure.

What’s wrong in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is a 32/64 bit issue. Is the Mac version the only 64 bit process that you've tested? Or perhaps you got lucky in the Windows and Linux versions in that they happen to return pointers of the form 0x00000000xxxxxxxx.

```
wand = lib.NewMagickWand()
```

NewMagickWand returns a pointer but you have not told ctypes to expect a pointer. As it stands ctypes defaults to a 32 bit integer for the return value. Add this line before you call NewMagickWand.

```
lib.NewMagickWand.restype = c_void_p
```

This tells ctypes that NewMagickWand returns a pointer.

Comment: As an aside, why not use the ready made Python interfaces to ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php

Answer (score 1):

I changed the following code:

```
lib.MagickReadImage(wand, 'mona-lisa.jpg')
```

to:

```
f2 = lib.MagickReadImage
f2.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p]
f2(wand, 'mona-lisa.jpg')
```

So, it works well.

Comment: In other words this is basically a 64 bit pointer issue. I just didn't get them all.